# Django Shell Default Database

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, raspberry-pi

I have an app named `steve_charts` with a `models.py` containing the class `Atmospheric`:

```
class Atmospheric(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(unique=True)
    temperature = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    humidity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    kpa = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)    

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'atmospheric'
```

This refers to a legacy DB I am accessing. In `settings.py` my postgresql DB is correctly defined:

```
    'steveDB':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'NAME': 'sensor_data',
        'USER': 'pi'
    },
    'default': { ## NOT EVEN USING THIS THING
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

I ran `python manage.py inspectdb --database steveDB > models.py` to get me a fresh new models.py no problems so far...

I ran `python manage.py makemigrations steve_charts` (which has been added to the installed apps section) and everything went smoothly. Django accessed my DB, inspected the table, made a new models.py for me no problem. Applied migrations no problem.

So now I would like to check the DB in the shell:

`python manage.py shell`
`>>>from steve_charts.models import Atmospheric` No problems.
`>>>Atmospheric.objects.all()` This should dump all the rows in the table, right? Instead I get `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: atmospheric`

Full stack trace:

```
>>> Atmospheric.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: atmospheric

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/pi/steve/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: atmospheric
>>> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: atmospheric
  File "<console>", line 1
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: atmospheric
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm using a RPi 3 model B. Raspberry Pi OS if that makes any difference.

Seems to me that the shell is only using the default DB as per trace. Is this expected behavior or am I being a stupid fella here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `using()` method in ORM query to specify database to use
Like
`Model.objects.using('steveDB').all()`

Comment: Adithya for the win! Cheers bud. Works for me in this scenario. 

As a side note, this DB has no `primary_key=True` so Django was searching for a column.id. My `atmospheric.time` column is always unique so I simply added `primary_key=True` to the time field definition and Django plays nice.